# How to write custom PySpark serializer

Tags: serialization, pyspark, pickle

I want to write a custom `pyspark` serializer. There is very little documentation online apart from details [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.PickleSerializer).

My logic is as follows:

- If I receive my special object, then I use custom logic to serialize/deserialize.
- Otherwise, use `cPickle` for the same.

The custom serializer looks like the following:

```py
from pyspark.serializers import FramedSerializer

class CustomSerializer(FramedSerializer):
    import cPickle as pickle 
    import CustomClass

    def dumps(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, CustomClass):
            bytes_str =  obj.serialize()
            bytes_str = '\1' + bytes_str
        elif isinstance(obj, CustomClass.Location):
            bytes_str =  obj.serialize()
            bytes_str = '\2' + bytes_str  
        else:
            bytes_str = pickle.dumps(obj)
            bytes_str = '\0' + bytes_str
        return bytes_str

    def loads(self, bytes_str):
        c = bytes_str[0]
        if c=='\1':
            obj = CustomClass()
            obj.parse_from_string(bytes_str[1:])
        elif c=='\2':
            obj = CustomClass.Location()
            obj.parse_from_string(bytes_str[1:])
        else:
            obj = pickle.loads(bytes_str[1:])
        return obj
```

While initiating `SparkContext`, I make sure I specify the custom serializer:

```py
serializer = CustomSerializer()
sc = SparkContext(appName='MyApp', serializer=serializer)
```

However, I still get error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1507044435666_0035/container_1507044435666_0035_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1507044435666_0035/container_1507044435666_0035_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1507044435666_0035/container_1507044435666_0035_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 272, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "<ipython-input-2-536808351108>", line 14, in dumps
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'CustomClass.Location'>: attribute lookup Location failed
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get his resolved?